# Spring Security Reference 3.2.4 documentation in PDF format

Tags: spring-security

With Spring Security 3.1.x in the URL for documentation under reference there used to be a folder or file for the PDF version of the Spring Security Reference.  In version 3.2.4 of the Spring Security Reference I only see a location for the htmlsingle folder which contains the reference documentation in 1 long html file.

What happened to the pdf version of the reference and where may I acquire it?  No google search was able to enlighten me on that subject.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a PDF generator such as the Save as PDF Chrome extension?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PDF support was removed in the Spring Security 3.2.x series due to an issue with the plugin. Take a look at this commit:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/c135179029343d4856e4be8d637ca36b5d49bb30

The last series that still supported PDF's was [3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT.pdf](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/springsecurity.pdf). There are 220 commits since that and the 3.2.0. Alternatively you can access the PDF of version [4.0.0.RC1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.RC1/reference/pdf/spring-security-reference.pdf) which is only 78 commits away from 3.2.0.RELEASE and does not have that many changes that actually affect docs files.